# Excel VBA - How To Retain Cell Value Even After The Reference Is Removed

Tags: vba, excel

How do you retain the value of a cell, for example cell B1 where B1 = A1, after the value of reference cell, A1 is removed?

No, I'm not looking for Copy & Paste Values (V). Is there a VBA code to do this?
As excel clear every variable values at the end of every subroutines. I would like to keep this value for reference all the time.

Comment: `Range("B1").Value = Range("B1").Value`

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would have been something simple but just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the value to the value, which will remove the references and formulas.

`Range("B1").Value = Range("B1").Value`